# Ошибка при restore Postgre

Tags: postgresql

При восстановлении бэкапа с помощью `pg_restore` вылетает ошибка

> pg_restore: [archiver] parallel restore is not supported with this archive file format

формат файла `tar`.

Почему?

Postgresql version 9.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сейчас восстанавливаете с архива и `pg_restore` не понимает его.

Вам нужно разархивировать и потом попробовать,

или при разархивации запустить `pg_restore`

попробуйте этот метод

**Backup**:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mydb | gzip > backup.gz
```

**Restore**:

```
gunzip -c backup.gz | psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mydb
```

вместо `pg_restore` можно использовать `psql`

Comment: Спасибо, работает!